# jquery plugin best structure and preventing method-calls on uninitialized objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, init

what you see here is the way i start with plugins:

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        init: function(){
            $this = this;
            alert('init '+$this.attr('id'));
        }
        ,
        show_id: function(){
            alert($this.attr('id'));
        }
    };

    var $this;
    // other vars

    $.fn.my_plug = function(method){
        var args = arguments;
        var $this = this;
        return this.each(function(){
            if (methods[method]){
                return methods[method].apply($this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
            } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method){
                return methods.init.apply($this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 0));
            } else {
                $.error('Method '+method+' does not exist!');
            }  
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

var a = true;

if (a) $('#object').my_plug(); // alerts "init object"

$('#object').my_plug('show_id'); // alerts "object"

var b = false;

if (b) $('#object_b').my_plug(); // does nothing

$('#object_b').my_plug('show_id'); // calls "show_id"-method … but $this is not defined. It should NOT call because this object is not initialized !!!
```

At the bottom you can see how i call the plugins methods.

First Question: Is there a cleaner way to get "this"/the object inside the methods?
I think it's quite uncool to first define the var outside the plugin, then inside the plugin and then inside the init-function. is there a cleaner way to do this?

As you can see at the bottom: I only want to call the plugin if the if-statements are true. If it's true than it calls init. Then I call a method of the plugin, which also works fine, because the "$this" is defined/initialized before.
BUT if the if-statment is not true and the "init"-method of the plugin is not called … i think it is unlogical that a method of the plugin can be called.

So this is Question #2: How can I prevent calling methods, if the object isn't initialized before?
If I call `$('#object_b').my_plug('show_id');` it should not do anything, because we didn't initialize the plugin. It should be only available if the plugin is initialized or rather if "$this" is defined.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted (thx to all):

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        init: function(){
            alert('init '+ this.attr('id'));
            //this.my_plug('show_id'); //call from inside the plugin
        }
        ,
        show_id: function(){
            alert(this.attr('id'));
        }
    };

    $.fn.my_plug = function(method){
        var args = arguments;
        var init = 'init-my_plug';
        return this.each(function() {
            var is_init = $(this).data(init);
            if (methods[method] && is_init){
                return methods[method].apply($(this), Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
            } else if (!is_init && (typeof method === 'object' || !method)){
                $(this).data(init, true);
                return methods.init.apply($(this), Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 0));
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

var a = true; // if a is set to false nothing happens

if (a) $('div').my_plug();
$('div').my_plug('show_id');
$('#div3').my_plug('show_id'); // also works on only one of the divs​​​​​​​​​​
```

Try it on: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ePwuR/)

Made some changes:

- data-value also has to include the plugin-name to prevent wrong
  behaviour if an other plugin uses the same technique.
- added "is_init" in the second if-statement

Answer (score 1):

For your first question you don't need to declare $this variable outside plugin. As you are calling the methods with `this` scope. `this` will be available in your methods. and what you can do is like

```
    var methods = {
    init: function(){
        var $this = $(this);     //local to this function
        alert('init '+$this.attr('id'));
    }
    ,
    show_id: function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        alert($this.attr('id'));
    }
};
```

For your second question you can attach data to the the dom object when you first call the plugin. You can check on subsequent calls if the plugin has been initialized on this object.

```
    $.fn.my_plug = function(method){
    var args = arguments;
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('your-plugin-inited'); //e.g.

        if (!data) {    //if no data is attached you can call init
            data = $this.data('your-plugin-inited', 1);
            return methods.init.apply($this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 0));
        }

        if (methods[method]){
            return methods[method].apply($this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
        } else {
            $.error('Method '+method+' does not exist!');
        }  
    });
  }
```

Check it out on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tqvjt/6/

I would recommend jQuery plugin patterns for more insight on plugin authoring.
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns

Comment: thx. the first part you posted does not work. but i found out, that if we write `$this = this` (without "var" at beginning), then it works. which is very strange!!

I don't understand your second part. first: isn't it better to combine the to ifs to `… } else if (methods[method]){ …`? second: you've defined "$this" inside the "this.each(function()…" which is very different from my code … what is the difference?

Comment: ok. your first part is completely wrong, because if you give "$this" an other value outside the plugin for instance in document.ready() than the value is overwritten. so we do need the `
var $this = this;`

Comment: ok. i edited your fiddle and now it **works exactly like i want it**. look here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTEFF/). that's it. i think this is a very good solution. thx for the input btw. I also deleted the $.error()-part because if i'm honest.. there is no need for it.
there is only one question i have: shall i mark your answer as correct or shall i answer my question by myself?

Comment: btw. at this fiddle you have to uncomment `//var a = true;`! ;)